# how can i show only selected checkbox productcode and price in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My view is like i want to show the selected textbox price and code to the controller

how can i do this

```
<div>
  <!--second line start-->
  <?php
  foreach ($enq_info as $ei) {
    echo form_open_multipart("Quotation/prepareQuote2/$ei->eid");
    if (!empty($quote_data)) {
    ?>
  <input name="quote_check" value="1" type="text" class="form-control">
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
  <input name="quote_check" value="no" type="text" class="form-control">
    <?php
  }
    ?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label for="firstname">Enquiry Id</label>
      <input name="e_id" id="e_id" value="<?php echo $ei->eid;?>" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="lastname">Company Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" value="<?php echo $ei->company_name;?>" class="form-control" />
    </div>      
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="lastname">Contact Person</label>
      <input type="text"  name="c_person" id="c_person" value="<?php echo $ei->c_person;?>" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Address</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address" value="<?php echo $ei->address;?>"><?php echo $ei->address;?></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="firstname">Attn Department</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="dept" name="dept" value="">
        <?php 
        echo $ei->c_person."&nbsp;Tel&nbsp;";
        if(empty($ei->p_contact))
          echo $ei->c_contact;
        else
          echo $ei->p_contact;
        ?>
      </textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="lastname">Quotation For</label>
      <select id="quotation_type" name="quotation_type" class="form-control m-b">
        <option value="Q_Manager">Q-Manager Quote</option>
        <option value="Q_Master">Q-Master Quote</option>
        <option value="Q_Manager_repair">Q-Manager Repair Quote</option>
      </select>
    </div> 
      <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="lastname">Discount</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="discount" name="discount"></textarea>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="lastname"></label><br><br>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="default_quote" value="Generate Default Quote" onClick="rerurn disable1();"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="showquote">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-md-12">   
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <tr>
                <td>Product Name</td>                                 
                <td>Product Code</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Action</td>
              </tr>
              <?php
              // print_r($quote_data);
              foreach ($product_data as $qd) {
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $qd->cp_name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $qd->cp_code;?></td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="product_price[]" value="<?php echo $qd->p_price;?>">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $qd->cp_name;?>" checked/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
            </table>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  <br><br>
  <!--for new manual quote-->
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  <!--third line start-->
```

how can i send the selected values price and also product code to the controller

Comment: What do you mean exactly? From your code I think your need addresses the `<tr>` generated inside of the `foreach ($product_data as $qd)` loop. And there it seems that you effectively show price and product code: so there what is not as you want?

Answer (score 1):

just add the product code - product price with comma seperated in a hidden field like below

12-20000,13-30000,14-200 and so on

and once received in controller process it with explode or other way.
hopes you understood.

Comment: dear amir i know your concerned but i am also want the edited price and shows only those price in controller ie selected how can it possible by this

Comment: i simply use this and the problem solved. <td><input type="text" name="product_code[<?php echo $qd->id;?>]" value="<?php echo $qd->cp_code;?>"></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="price[<?php echo $qd->id;?>]" value="<?php echo $qd->p_price;?>"></td>